# between two activity i want to set progress bar

Tags: android, android-activity, progress-bar

```
Intent s = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainmusicActivity.class);
s.putExtra("tid",tid1);             
s.putExtra("songlist",r);
s.putExtra("position", position);
System.out.println(tid1);           
//s.putStringArrayListExtra("list",r);              
startActivity(s);
```

//the above code one activity to another activity connection, at the time of going other activity display blank screen here song is streaming time is black screen. so i want to set progress bar here how? pls help me..........

Comment: @imran-khan you beat my edit... argh

Comment: ok which activity i want to implement this code?

Answer (score 0):

Use service for playing music and update progress bar when start new activity.

Comment: https://github.com/josef-jelinek/tiny-mod-player/tree/master/app.gamod-player/src/gamod/client